# php - uploading file using doesn't give error

Tags: php

what i want to do is to upload image to the server using php

this is my code

```
<?php
try {
    $name = isset($_POST['variable2']);
    $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".isset($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $file_name = isset($_FILES['file1']['name']);
    $file_loc = isset($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name']);
    $file_size = isset($_FILES['file1']['size']);
    $file_type = isset($_FILES['file1']['type']);
    $folder="uploads123/";
    $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
    $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
    $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);
if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
    {
        echo "good";
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }
} catch (PDOException $pe) {
                        die("Error occurred:" . $pe->getMessage());
                    }       

?>
```

these are my problems

1. why is it that the output it just the "error" from the if statement? it doesn't give details about the error even if i'm using try and catch.
2. even if i give a wrong foldername(the directory where the image to be uploaded) it just give me output like "error" from the if statement.
   it doesn't give error that the folder doesn't exist on the server.

thank you.

Comment: you are not setting your vars correctly: `$file_name = isset($_FILES['file1']['name'])` -> `$file_name` is set to `true`, but not to the name of the file.

Comment: `move_uploaded_file` just return true or false without throw any exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your html form is like that?

```
<form action="target.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<!-- Content -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Try changing PDOException to Exception

Comment: i dont know how to use that code. but ill give it a try. thank you

Comment: Just paste on the top of the php file and it should throw every errors

Comment: i tried it paste the code? but it doesn't throw errors.

Comment: Sorry just found the correct solution You are trying to find a PDOException instead of an Exception - just updated the answer

Comment: i tried it sir. changing the PDOException to Exception. where can i upload the html file and php?

Comment: Just paste on your topic. 
try to var_dump($_FILES)

Answer (score 0):

Does folder exists? check privilegies on server for folder

Good way before move file:

```
$upload_dir = '/uploads123';
if(!is_dir($upload_dir)){
    mkdir($upload_dir, 0777); // you may set your access rule
}
```

Then you can try move file to this dir

Answer (score 0):

`isset()` returns a boolean (true or false)

`$file_loc` will not be a valid file location, but is a boolean:

```
$file_loc = isset($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name']); // $file_loc = true
```

`move_uploaded_file` wil fail as it has no valid file to move and returns `false`. Your code will echo `"error"` as a result of `move_uploaded_file` returning `false`.

There is no Exception thrown, let alone a PDOException.